# Google Script star an e-mail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have a Google Script that processes the inbox looking for missing e-mails, and then sends out a summary of missing e-mails to my inbox:

```
var user;
var summary = "";
Logger.log("Checking last emails...");
user_list.forEach(function(user) {
var no_user_hit = true;
var query = 'from:'+user.user+' in:anywhere newer_than:' + user.deadline + 'd';
Logger.log(query);
var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
if (check_subject(messages[j].getSubject(), user.subject)) {
no_user_hit = false;   
}
}
}

if (no_user_hit == true) {
Logger.log("Sending email with summary...");
summary = summary + "No messages from "+user.user+" with subject "+user.subject+" for the last "+user.deadline+" days \n"; 
}
});

if (summary.length > 0) {
GmailApp.sendEmail(me, email_subject_to_your, summary);
}
}
```

I would like to star each e-mail being sent as a summary, I have tried starMessage(message) but that hasn't worked out.

Comment: Could you please check the console log for any error messages?

Comment: The script is in .gs format, the log doesn't tell me anything unusual, but if I do GmailApp.starMessage(summary); I will get the error: Cannot find method starMessage(string). (line 200, file "Code")

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#starMessage%28GmailMessage%29), the parameter should be a `GmailMessage`, not a string. Are you sure you are providing the correct parameter?

Comment: Yes, I seem not to be using **GmailMessage**, but a string. But is there a way to star a message from a string, which is **summary**, in the **sendEmail** method?

Comment: I think I got it now! I simply used  

'var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
 var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
 GmailApp.starMessage(message);'

and it got the message starred. Now I just need to figure the array to make this start the message straight when it arrives and not afterwards. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! I have posted these findings as an answer so feel free to accept it if you are happy with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the [GmailApp.starMessage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#starMessage%28GmailMessage%29) accepts a [GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) object, but you are supplying the method with a string (as seen from the error message you are getting).

After you have sent your message, you will need to find it again in user's mailbox and then star it.

There is an [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757025/getting-thread-id-of-a-mail-sent-through-google-scripts) about retrieving a just-sent message for further processing - that might help with this.

Comment: Thanks Robert, one more question though, as I'm fairly new to Google Scripts - how would I find that message I just sent in the inbox, and then star it? I always get the previous message starred once the new one gets in. 

I have this snippet for sending e-mail that contains the body of the message:

    `if (summary.length > 0) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(me, email_subject_to_your, summary);
    }`

Comment: Dunno, I am also not very versed with Apps Script.:) But I would guess you can use the [search()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search%28String,Integer,Integer%29) method and find the just-sent email by sender, recipient and subject (or any other information that you know is unique to that particular mail).

Comment: Thanks, already tried that, but I guess I'll have to fiddle with it around a bit more. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Perhaps [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757025/getting-thread-id-of-a-mail-sent-through-google-scripts) may be of further assistance, then.

Comment: Brilliant! Does exactly what I need. Thanks a million Robert :)